# Handling Promise.reject in bluebird's done(resolve, reject)

Tags: javascript, bluebird

My understanding of promises is not perfect.

Pleas help me to write code correctly.

There is function:

```
function getData(name){
     if(!name){
          return P.reject(new Error('Name is required'));
     }
  ...}
```

and here is another function

```
function doStuff(){
     return something.getData().done(null, function(err) {
        console.log('ok');
        });
  ...}
```

In bluebird when I call doStuff() it should handle rejected promise as Promise.prototype.catch() does

```
 .done(
      [function(any value) fulfilledHandler],
      [function(any error) rejectedHandler]
 ) -> undefined
```

but error still being thrown:

```
 ERROR: Name is required
```

Why and how to handle it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe. In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s2qeodug/1/) the only output that is shown is `ok`. The error might be at another place. Please create a minimal run able example that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why are you using `done`, especially when you want to `return` something from your `doStuff` function? Always use `then` - `done` was useful when unhandled rejection warnings weren't a thing but is deprecated now.